# Cast a dynamic Flask URL route path to string

Tags: python, flask, routes

I have a catch-all route set up in Flask and I want to parse the URL regardless of the length.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
app.route('/')
app.route('/<path:path>')
def main(path=None):
  if path == None:
    return 'foo'
  else:
    return 'bar'
if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```

The problem is I'm getting a 404 Not Found error and I don't know why. The url I'm using to test is **/hello/world/**. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the error is raised in the code snippet you provided? `.spit()` returns a list of strings so I assume the error is raised somewhere below the `for` statement in the part of your code you didn't provide. Additionally, you might take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15117416/3991125

Comment: Please show the full traceback. As albert says, it doesn't seem to be coming from this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot `@` before routing decorators. Change it this way:

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/<path:path>')
```

and it will work.