# Generic endpoint in Flask

Tags: python, flask

In Flask, is it possible to have a generic endpoint which can serve different requests, I take an example, suppose I have a handler for `"/"` and I want that all request is handled by this handler to generate a reply. A request like `"/person/767"` or `"/car/324"` should also handled by the same endpoint and it is going to generate the reply base on resource requested. Is that possible and if yes, how ?

Comment: Looks like this does what you need: [Capture arbitrary path in flask route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15117416/capture-arbitrary-path-in-flask-route)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want an endpoint to literally capture everything after a particular slash, you can use a *path* placeholder in your route definition.

```
@app.route('/<path:path>')
```

A more detailed example in this answer:

[Capture Arbitrary Path in Flask Route](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15117464/2969880)

Comment: exactly what i'm looking for, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can register multiple routes to one view function

```
from flask import Flask


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/car/<id>')
@app.route('/person/<id>')
def generic_endpoint(id=None):
    ...
```

or, as pointed out by @sql_knievel, use `<path:path>`.